# DistinctCount with a condition in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I have a distinctcount in a PowerPivot on a column "Pers ID". I would like to add a condition on this distinct count: only DistinctCount when in Column "Month" the month is later or equal to November (example). I tried to look for a solution on the forum and came out with this:

CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Alles 24_07_21'[Pers_ID]);'Alles 24_07_21'[Month_N]>=11)

If I try this I get the following error message:

*Calculation error in measure 'Alles 24_07_21'[Distinct Count]: DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type Integer. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.*

I hope somebody can help me out. Does this formula makes any sense in the first place? What can I do to avoid the error? Column "Pers ID" is formatted in the source file as a number and Month as a number a well.

| Pers_ID | Month_N |
| --- | --- |
| 643328 | 11 |
| 643329 | 11 |
| 643328 | 10 |
| 643329 | 12 |

For example...in the table above, the DistinctCount should be 0 for Pers_ID number "643328" because it has a Month_N < 11. The DistinctCount for Pers_ID "643328" should be 1 because it has Month_N >= 11.
I also have a few filters on the Pivot Table but I don't think that is a problem.

Thx a lot in advance!

Best regards,

Nick

Comment: Can you please provide sample data [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow). Also, is the data type of `Month_N` is integer?

Comment: I tried to add what you requested. Data type in the source file are for both columns "number". Thx a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The formula seems fine but it appears to be a data type error. It doesn't matter as much what the source file data type is as long as it's correct in your Power Pivot model. From the error message, it would seem that `Month_N` column is typed as text in your model.

One way to test this would be to try replacing `11` with `"11"` in your measure. If you don't get the same error, then this is very likely the culprit.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, did always try to change the data type in the source file! It does the job for the error message when I change the data type in the Power Pivot Model. But...if I verify the result of the formula, I do get records which also have a month "10" for example. So I'm not there yet. Any idea? Thx a lot in advance!!

Comment: Note that writing `'Alles'[Month_N] >= 11` *replaces* the filter context for this column. If you just want it as an *additional* filter write `KEEPFILTERS('Alles'[Month_N] >= 11)` instead.

Comment: Thx Alexis! Really appreciate your help! Unfortunately...this still gives me results with also month "10" for example. My formula now is: CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Alles 24_07_21'[Pers_ID]);KEEPFILTERS('Alles 24_07_21'[Month_N]>=11)). But If I select in my Pivot Table filter "10" as october, my distinctcount is 0 (which is correct). Hope you can help me out.

Comment: So it gives the correct result but a zero rather than a blank? At this point, it should be a separate question.

Comment: Sorry to confuse things. If I have my pivot table filter on 11 (November), I still get records in the distinctcount results which alsof have a month 10 (October) with this formula (>=11). If I change the pivot table filter to 10 and use the same formula (>=11), my distinct counts are blank.